# Set up SSL cert for subdomain to work with https, Centos 7

Tags: centos, ssl, certificate, https, subdomain

I've set up a subdomain `sm.webscraping.pro` working thru **http** (Centos 7). Yet as to **https**, the https://  returns rather *the main domain content* (webscraping.pro).

Any suggestion how to plug in another SSL cert for subdomain and set up https?

**Note**: The present SSL certificate pertaining to the domain cannot be used for both the domain and its subdomains at the same time.

### Update (browser does not recognize SSL certificates)

**1)** I've followed @Alex suggestion to use dehydrated. As I've stepped after [the tutorial](https://ratfactor.com/slackware/dehydrated), I eventually got smooth thru all steps and the certs are in the `certs` folder.
See the `dehydrated` folder content:

```
[root@webscraping dehydrated]# tree .
.
├── accounts
│   ├── aHR0cHM6Ly9hY21lLXN0YWdpbmctdjAyLmFwaS5sZXRzZW5jcnlwdC5vcmcvZGlyZWN0b3J5Cg
│   │   ├── account_id.json
│   │   ├── account_key.pem
│   │   └── registration_info.json
│   ├── aHR0cHM6Ly9hY21lLXN0YWdpbmcuYXBpLmxldHNlbmNyeXB0Lm9yZy9kaXJlY3RvcnkK
│   ├── aHR0cHM6Ly9hY21lLXYwMi5hcGkubGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnL2RpcmVjdG9yeQo -> aHR0cHM6Ly9hY21lLXYwMS5hcGkubGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnL2RpcmVjdG9yeQo
│   ├── aHR0cHM6Ly9hY21lLXYwMjIuYXBpLmxldHNlbmNyeXB0Lm9yZy9kaXJlY3RvcnkK
│   └── aHR0cHM6Ly9hY21lLXYwMS5hcGkubGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnL2RpcmVjdG9yeQo
│       ├── account_id.json
│       ├── account_key.pem
│       └── registration_info.json
├── aHR0cHM6Ly9hY21lLXYwMS5hcGkubGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnL2RpcmVjdG9yeQo
├── archive
├── certs
│   └── sm.webscraping.pro
│       ├── cert-1637096617.csr
│       ├── cert-1637096617.pem
│       ├── cert.csr -> cert-1637096617.csr
│       ├── cert.pem -> cert-1637096617.pem
│       ├── chain-1637096617.pem
│       ├── chain.pem -> chain-1637096617.pem
│       ├── fullchain-1637096617.pem
│       ├── fullchain.pem -> fullchain-1637096617.pem
│       ├── privkey-1637096617.pem
│       └── privkey.pem -> privkey-1637096617.pem
├── chains
├── conf.d
│   └── local.sh
├── config
├── domains.txt
├── hook.d
└── hook.sh
```

**2)** I've modified the **httpd.conf** file to refer to the certificate files:

```
 ...
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public
    ServerName sm.webscraping.pro 
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sm.webscraping.pro
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/fullchain.pem

  </VirtualHost>
```

**3)** Restarted Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

Yet there are 2 problems remaining:

1. A browser treats the https://sm.webscraping.pro as **unsecure resource**.
2. Besides, the **sm.webscraping.pro** returns the **content of the main domain**.

:-(

**What might be wrong?**

**Any way to fix?**

### Update 2 - browser seem to check the main domain certificate against sm.webscraping.pro

When checked the sm.webscraping.pro at an online SSL check tool the latter has returned me the info of the main domain certificate:

**Note:** in this check result: **None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (sm.webscraping.pro).**

There is seemingly a **conflict** between the certificate of the official SSL issuing authority (CA) and the certificate of ACME "Automatic Certificate Management Environment"... How to resolve it to **make both working** ?

> sm.webscraping.pro resolves to 185.221.154.249
> Server Type: nginx
> The certificate should be trusted by all major web browsers (all the correct intermediate certificates are installed).
> The certificate was issued by Sectigo.
> The certificate will expire in 323 days.
> **None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was
> entered (sm.webscraping.pro).** You may receive an error when accessing
> this site in a web browser. Learn more about name mismatch errors.

> **Server**
> Common name: webscraping.pro
> SANs: webscraping.pro, [www.webscraping.pro](http://www.webscraping.pro)
> Valid from September 5, 2021 to October 6, 2022
> Serial Number: fbab39085b740febae1e9cba4cee3dd8 Signature
> Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
> Issuer: Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

> **Chain**
> Common name: Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
> Organization: Sectigo Limited
> Location: Salford, Greater Manchester, GB
> Valid from November 1, 2018 to December 31, 2030
> Serial Number: 7d5b5126b476ba11db74160bbc530da7
> Signature Algorithm: sha384WithRSAEncryption
> Issuer: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority

Another evidence:
[image]

### Update 3 - the present VirtualHost configuration

```
185.221.154.249:8443   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server webscraping.pro (/home/admin/conf/web/webscraping.pro.httpd.ssl.conf:1)
         port 8443 namevhost webscraping.pro (/home/admin/conf/web/webscraping.pro.httpd.ssl.conf:1)
                 alias www.webscraping.pro
         port 8443 namevhost programs.educamatch.com (/home/admin/conf/web/programs.educamatch.com.httpd              .ssl.conf:1)
                 alias www.programs.educamatch.com
185.221.154.249:8080   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server webscraping.pro (/home/admin/conf/web/webscraping.pro.httpd.conf:1)
         port 8080 namevhost webscraping.pro (/home/admin/conf/web/webscraping.pro.httpd.conf:1)
                 alias www.webscraping.pro
         port 8080 namevhost programs.educamatch.com (/home/admin/conf/web/programs.educamatch.com.httpd              .conf:1)
                 alias www.programs.educamatch.com
         port 8080 namevhost testing-ground.webscraping.pro (/home/admin/conf/web/testing-ground.webscra              ping.pro.httpd.conf:1)
                 alias www.testing-ground.webscraping.pro
         port 8080 namevhost test.webscraping.pro (/home/admin/conf/web/test.webscraping.pro.httpd.conf:              1)
                 alias www.test.webscraping.pro
         port 8080 namevhost sm.webscraping.pro (/home/admin/conf/web/sm.webscraping.pro.httpd.conf:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server sm.webscraping.pro (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:59)
         port 80 namevhost sm.webscraping.pro (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:59)
         port 80 namevhost sm.webscraping.pro (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:59)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server sm.webscraping.pro (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:71)
         port 443 namevhost sm.webscraping.pro (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:71)
         port 443 namevhost sm.webscraping.pro (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:71)
```

### Update 4

In the `/home/admin/conf/web/` I've found the following:

```
nginx.programs.educamatch.com.conf_letsencrypt   ssl.programs.educamatch.com.pem
nginx.sm.webscraping.pro.conf_letsencrypt        ssl.webscraping.pro.ca
nginx.webscraping.pro.conf_letsencrypt           ssl.webscraping.pro.crt
programs.educamatch.com.httpd.conf               ssl.webscraping.pro.key
programs.educamatch.com.httpd.ssl.conf           ssl.webscraping.pro.pem
programs.educamatch.com.nginx.conf               testing-ground.webscraping.pro.httpd.conf
programs.educamatch.com.nginx.ssl.conf           testing-ground.webscraping.pro.nginx.conf
sm.webscraping.pro.httpd.conf                    test.webscraping.pro.httpd.conf
sm.webscraping.pro.nginx.conf                    test.webscraping.pro.nginx.conf
sm.webscraping.pro.snginx.conf                   webalizer.webscraping.pro.conf
snginx.programs.educamatch.com.conf_letsencrypt  webscraping.pro.auth
snginx.sm.webscraping.pro.conf_letsencrypt       webscraping.pro.httpd.conf
snginx.webscraping.pro.conf_letsencrypt          webscraping.pro.httpd.ssl.conf
ssl.programs.educamatch.com.ca                   webscraping.pro.nginx.conf
ssl.programs.educamatch.com.crt                  webscraping.pro.nginx.ssl.conf
ssl.programs.educamatch.com.key
```

Probably generated by VestaCP.
Should I put the generated Let Encrypt certificates into here ?

### Update 5

For the main domain I have the following (used by Vesta) files in `/home/admin/conf/web`:

```
ssl.webscraping.pro.ca
ssl.webscraping.pro.crt
ssl.webscraping.pro.key
ssl.webscraping.pro.pem
```

While the files generated by **dehydrated** for the subdomain are **only these** in `/etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro`:

```
cert-1637096617.csr
cert-1637096617.pem
cert.csr
cert.pem
chain-1637096617.pem
chain.pem
fullchain-1637096617.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey-1637096617.pem
privkey.pem
```

How to correctly map them for the `.ca`, `.crt`, `.key` and `.pem` files into the `/home/admin/conf/web` folder ?

### Update 6

Following @Alex 's  comment I've copied `fullchain-xxx.pem` into `ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.crt` and `privkey-xxx.pem` into `ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.key` into the `/home/admin/conf/web` directory. Then I've added them as the certificate and the certificate key accordingly in Vesta CP (in the `SSL` section of the `WEB` tab for the sm.webscraping.pro domain). See image below:

[image]

Yet still no evidence of SSL working:
[image]

Any way out ?

### Update 7

I've updated VestaCP and followed to add cert from CP using Let's Encrypt.
Seemingly a positive result:

[image]

Yet still problem with identifying SSL:

[image]

Why is that? Any suggestion of **when the SSL cert is spread throughout the web** ?

Comment: Just obtain free SSl certificate from letsencrypt.org for particular subdomain (CN - common name) only  `sm.webscraping.pro` and add it into web server configuration, then  TLD will run on existing one and subdomain on another SSL certificate. You can use [dehydrated](https://github.com/dehydrated-io/dehydrated) bash script from your CentOS host directly to get SSL certificate

Comment: Honestly your post and user profile altogether feels more like an advertisement of your website than an actual question. I can't even decide whether to post an answer or to flag as spam.

Comment: @user1686, sorry. No way to advertise the website. Let me correct the question for you to have peace to post your answer.

Comment: @Alex, I've followed your recommendations using `dehydrated`, yet not much luck. Could you see the **Update** section and respond?

Comment: @user1686, based on the *second Update* there is a conflict between the certificate of the SSL issuing authority (CA) and the certificate of ACME "Automatic Certificate Management Environment" ... how to resolve it to **make both working** ?

Comment: Are you using ACME with Sectigo or with LetsEncrypt? Can you check `httpd -S` to see if the vhost is being read correctly?

Comment: @user1686, I use ACME with LetsEncrypt. Sectigo CA has issued a paid certificate that was installed by the hosting paid support more than a year earlier.

Comment: @user1686, should I use Vesta CP to add Lets Encrypt cert to the subdomain http://joxi.ru/12MQy10CwdJ9j2 ?

Comment: @user1686, I've done `httpd -S` to output VirtualHost configuration. See **Update 3**.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin If your host managed by `Vista CP` then it defiantly overriding direct changes in apache, so, supply letsenrypt's key to VistaCP. P.S: stick with only one solution, either you managing host via VistaCP or you do all your stuff manually, otherwise on any update everything will be screwed again.

Comment: @Alex, thanks. So, should I load the certificate of LetsEncrypt (gained by `dehydrated`) directly thru Vesta CP interface - http://joxi.net/12MQy10CwdJ9j2 ?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin Yes, just make sure that files names that VistaCP using internally matching those that you got with `dehydrated`.  Compare with those files you got for primary domain

Comment: @Alex, thanks. See my **Update 5**.

Comment: `fulchain.pem` is symlink to the latest obtained certificate, the same is with `private.pem`, so you need `ls -la` to find where it point to and copy `fullchain-xxxxx.pem` to `sm.webscraping.pro.crt` and `sm.webscraping.pro.key` to /home/admin/conf/web then add it from CP to appropriate subdomain

Comment: @Alex, so `fullchain.pem -> fullchain-1637096617.pem` and `privkey.pem -> privkey-1637096617.pem`.  Now should I copy `fullchain-1637096617.pem` into `sm.webscraping.pro.crt` and `privkey-1637096617.pem` into `sm.webscraping.pro.key`. 
What about `sm.webscraping.pro.ca` and `sm.webscraping.pro.pem` files, how to *produce* them?

Comment: @Alex, I've done as you've suggested (see **Update 6**), yet still **no evidence of SSL working** ... Any comments ?

Comment: 1. Shouldn't be `LetsEncrypt` checked too? 2. CSR - it is certificate request that generated by you based on your private key, when certificate authority received it, they signing it and return you signed certificate, that are two files you need it (certificate will already included CA of signer inside of it) It looks like your HostingPanel supports LetsEncrypt, why don't you contact hosting support to clarify it in your language

Comment: @Alex, I've updated Vesta and added a cert thru CP (**Update 7**). Still... not working...

Answer (score 1):

The certificate doesn't have any influence on what the web server returns. Only the web server's *virtual host* configuration influences what the web server returns for each individual hostname.

In Apache, you must define *two* `<VirtualHost>` blocks for each new subdomain, one for `:80` and another for `:443`, and both blocks must specify your domain as `ServerName`. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/.../example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/.../example.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The web server will always use your browser's HTTP `Host:` header to match against the virtual host's `ServerName/ServerAlias`, regardless of certificate being served (e.g. even if you use the completely wrong certificate).

Note that the `NameVirtualHost` option has been obsolete since Apache 2.4.0 (released in 2012) and is just ignored; in this version, all vhosts are name-based vhosts by default.

Similarly, `Order` and `Allow from` are both obsolete; they're replaced by `Require all granted` in Apache 2.4, with the old versions still being handled by a compatibility module.

Comment: thank for your answer. Yet  after I've followed @Alex recommendations using `dehydrated` for generating certificates => **not much success**. Could you take a look at the **Update** section and respond?

Comment: Are you sure you don't accidentally have the same domain in _another_ vhost's ServerName or ServerAlias lost somewhere in /etc/apache2?

Comment: I've checked this,  **no**. Both `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` and `/etc/httpd/conf.d` have no hints to that.