# LetsEncrypt certificate (generated thru Vesta CP) does not work for subdomain at Centos 7

Tags: centos, certificate, https, ssl-certificate, control-panel

### 1 ) Add cert

I've **added up a SSL certificate** for a subdomain **sm.webscraping.pro** (VPS, Centos 7) at VestaCP using **Lets Encrypt** support option, see below:

[image]

### 2 ) Files

The **certificate files** are in the directory `/home/admin/conf/web/`:

```
ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.ca
ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.crt
ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.key
ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.pem
```

The file `sm.webscraping.pro.httpd.ssl.conf` in the same directory has the following content:

```
<VirtualHost 185.221.154.249:8443>

    ServerName sm.webscraping.pro

    ServerAdmin info@sm.webscraping.pro
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/sm.webscraping.pro.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/sm.webscraping.pro.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/sm.webscraping.pro.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        SSLRequireSSL
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        #php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.ca

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        RGroups apache
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/shttpd.sm.webscraping.pro.conf*
</VirtualHost>
```

### 3 ) Not working :-(

Yet as to https, **the SSL cert still does not work**: [image]

### 4 Check cert

When **checking the SSL certificate**, the checker returns a SSL cert pertaining to the main domain:

**Note**: The present SSL certificate pertaining to the main domain cannot be used for both the domain and its subdomains at the same time.

[image]

### Any suggestion? Is something missing ?

### Update

Beside **`/home/admin/conf/web/sm.webscraping.pro.httpd.ssl.conf`**, [automatically generated] file, I've earlier set up virtual hosts for 80 and 443 ports:

**`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public
  ServerName sm.webscraping.pro 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName sm.webscraping.pro
  DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/fullchain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your Apache config is for port 8443. I don’t see that port in the address bar screenshot.

Comment: @DanielB, when hitting the post 8433 I've got "The site can't be reached". http://joxi.ru/L21jgLYCzBK5bA See my *Update* too.

Comment: See also my prev. question: https://superuser.com/q/1687767/259471

Comment: Why are you reposting the same question. Makes it extremely difficult to answer your question.

Comment: I manually navigated to https://sm.webscraping.pro was redirected to https://webscraping.pro/wp-login.php and my browser indicates it’s a secure connection

Comment: @Ramhound, "are you reposting the same question" - sorry for misleading... the present question is one of my stress though. What browser do you use ?

Comment: Safari; CentOS 7 needs the new Let’s Encrypt root CA installed

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks, I see it working...