# A subdomain returns a main domain content when HTTPS

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, domain, https, subdomain

I've set up [LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on my subdomain](https://superuser.com/questions/1689717/letsencrypt-certificate-generated-thru-vesta-cp-does-not-work-for-subdomain-at), sm.webscraping.pro.
Yet the subdomain serves the main domain (webscraping.pro) content at HTTPS, while its own (as intended) content at HTTP.

How to make HTTPS requests to return subdomain's own content, not the one of main domain?

1. The subdomain source folder:  **/home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html**
2. The domain source folder:  **/home/admin/web/webscraping.pro/public_html**

The **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public
  ServerName sm.webscraping.pro 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName sm.webscraping.pro
  DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/dehydrated/certs/sm.webscraping.pro/fullchain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Yet, there is another "VirtualHost defining" file **/home/admin/conf/web/sm.webscraping.pro.httpd.ssl.conf** with the following:

```
<VirtualHost 185.221.154.249:443>

    ServerName sm.webscraping.pro
    ServerAdmin info@sm.webscraping.pro
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/sm.webscraping.pro.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/sm.webscraping.pro.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/sm.webscraping.pro.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        SSLRequireSSL
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        #php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sm.webscraping.pro.ca

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        RGroups apache
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/shttpd.sm.webscraping.pro.conf*
</VirtualHost>
```

As seen in the VH files, the **DocumentRoot** parameter maps to the `.../sm.webscraping.pro/public_html/public` folder, not to the main domain one. **What's wrong then**?

`.htaccess` file inside the project root folder, **/home/admin/web/sm.webscraping.pro/public_html**.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How to make HTTPS requests to return subdomain's own content, not of main domain?

Should I use a **redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP** like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8371/1230477) ?

Comment: Just to exclude possible oversights, have you cleared your browsercache after the change and/or force refreshed the webpage after the change, just to rule out that you are not loading a cached page.

Comment: also, usually http is public_html, https is private_html

Comment: @LPChip, "have you cleared your browsercache after the change and/or force refreshed the webpage" - I did and this has not helped...